# How to resolve issue on Google Play upload new APK, but the target SDK version being lower than what was in the previous version of the app

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, version

How to resolve issue on Google Play upload new APK, but the target SDK version being lower than what was in the previous version of the app.

My previous version is

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

and this new version

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Thanks

Comment: whats the error you get when you do this in Google play?

Comment: SDK target version being lower than was in the previous version of the app.